# How to Download Documents from a a Sharepoint Document Library using Workflow Foundation?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, tfsbuild, workflow-foundation

I have some Test, Security, Project Management and some other word documents in TFS2010 source control under Documents folder. Does anybody know how to access them in order to download and copy to a local path?

Those files are not physically under $/... folder, though they have a Sharepoint web server path like: "`http://myServer/sites/MyProyect/Test/Tests_P13_F00120.doc`". I have tried to use `DownloadFiles` activity without success due to it needs a path which starts with $/. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Those files are not in source control - they are in SharePoint.

Comment: @JohnSaunders : Yeah, I mentioned it "though they have a Sharepoint web server path...". But is there any way to get them through workflows? Thanks for answering

Comment: Please say what you're trying to accomplish. "Get them" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: When I say get them, I mean download for example all documents under Test folder from my Sharepoint site (which is connected to my Team Build 2010) using Team Build Workflow. Example: `http://myServer/sites/MyProyect/Test/*.doc`

Comment: Look into the SharePoint client-side API. I'm looking at an example right now in "Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Developer Reference", Chapter 5, "Client-Side Technologies", listing 5-25. It only downloads a single document, but that suggests there's a way to download an entire folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DownloadFiles` is not an activity you can make use of, it's meant to deal with files residing in Source control.

Instead, you need to establish a connection to the Sharepoint Copy service of your TFS, which resides at `http://<Site>/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx`. We did this by adding a Service Reference in our build solution.

We then implemented a build activity that does basically the opposite of what you are after: during TFS build it uploads documents into Sharepoint.

The instantiation looks like this:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://<Site>/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx");

CopySoapClient copyService = new CopySoapClient(binding,endpointAddress);
```

This copy service exposes a `GetItem` method, this is the one you should probably be invoking.

I 'm not aware if this `GetItem` is capable of supporting a `http://myServer/sites/MyProject/Test/*.doc` kind of thing